# How to determine if a post is using the divi pagebuilder or the builtin wordpress wysiwig editor

Tags: php, wordpress

Im editing the single.php template file, and need some sort of conditional statement to determine if the current post is running the divi pagebuilder or if the_content() is just outputting the the standard wysiwyg editor content.

The current solution im thinking about is using css to show and hide certain divs, but im hoping theres a better solution using php.

i tried this to see if the tinymce editor was working or not, but it didnt work, and either way, wasnt specific to divis pagebuilder, mostly would target the defaul wysiwig editor.

var is_editor_active = function(editor_id){

```
    if(typeof tinyMCE == 'undefined'){
        return false;
    }

    if( typeof editor_id == 'undefined' ){
        editor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    }else{
        editor = tinyMCE.EditorManager.get(editor_id);
    }

    if(editor == null){
        return false;
    }

     return !editor.isHidden();

};
```

Comment: show the code you already tried ?

Comment: i edited my answer, but still the code i tried didnt work